# How to parse or convert paypal ipn message to json object or object?

Tags: json, paypal-ipn

Paypal IPN message format is kind weird where spaces are "&", @ becomes "%40" and so on and I do not know what do you call that format.

I tried replacing those characters like this:

```
var set0 = receipt.split('&').join(',&');
var set1 = set0.replace(/&/g,'\n');
var set2 = set1.replace(/%40/g,'@');
var set3 = set2.replace(/%2C/g,',');
var set4 = set3.replace(/%3A/g,':');
var set5 = set4.split('+').join(' ');
var set6 = set5.split('=').join(': ');
var test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(set6));
console.log(test);
```

I got the exact arrangement that I want by replacing those characters:

```
amount1: 1.00,
amount3: 14.99,
address_status: confirmed,
subscr_date: 17:41:18 Aug 07, 2016 PDT,
payer_id: NZKP3G9KN3Y5G,
address_street: 1 Main St,
mc_amount1: 1.00,
mc_amount3: 14.99
```

But the problem is I can not get the value let say:

```
console.log(test.amount1);
```

It says **invalid**. Please advise thank you.

This is the sample IPN Post back I get from Paypal sandbox:

```
amount1=1.00&amount3=14.99&address_status=confirmed&subscr_date=17%3A41%3A18+Aug+07%2C+2016+PDT&payer_id=NZKP3G9KN3Y5G&address_street=1+Main+St&mc_amount1=1.00&mc_amount3=14.99&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&first_name=test&reattempt=1&address_country_code=US&address_name=test+buyer&notify_version=3.8&subscr_id=I-LYDJAAW6R5J0&custom=QuQHkL8EQ2XLYD6Tz&payer_status=verified&business=billing-facilitator%40testmail.com&address_country=United+States&address_city=San+Jose&verify_sign=AiPC9BjkCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacAm05VARKo4Q3kMeDNMwELG8cel.7&payer_email=billing-buyer-2%40testmail.com&btn_id=3394935&last_name=buyer&address_state=CA&receiver_email=billing-facilitator%40testmail.com&recurring=1&txn_type=subscr_signup&item_name=Premium+with+Trial&mc_currency=USD&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&period1=1+D&period3=1+M&ipn_track_id=1e857dd5b422e
```

And I used **replace** method (the code above) to get the desired format.

Comment: You should probably consider showing more of your code, as well as the inputs (i.e., an example of the response from paypal -- *before* you start hacking at it). While I'm not going to be able to help you with this question (I'm not familiar with paypal-ipn) it seems pretty apparent that the response you're getting is **not** json (possibly HTML encoded?)

Comment: Parse it properly with a library like `qs`, instead of replacing random characters manually.

Comment: @zerkms - thank you for the suggestion, i will try to library. :)

Comment: @zerkms - the QS  package did all the trick . . . thank you so much :D

Comment: finally case closed :)